# Variable Image name AND UIImageView

Tags: xcode, variables, uiimageview

So I bring in 3 variables for each level, assign them temp values, and want to change images depending on the values.

```
for (NSInteger row = 1; row < 11; row++) {  // 1 to 10

//Recall Key Name and save the Data Stored to new array
    NSArray *allLevelStatsArray = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:_allDataStats];

    _tempLevel = [allLevelStatsArray[0] intValue];   // = 1
    _tempPoints = [allLevelStatsArray[1] intValue];  // = 500
    _tempStar = [allLevelStatsArray[2] intValue];    // = 2

   // For each level, assign the level image the correct star image
   // _top3Stars_Level1 for Levels 1 - 10;   Stars 0 - 3
   // Hard coding, this works
   _top3Stars_Level1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"2-stars.png"];

   // Create the level image to assign the stars
   NSString *top3StarsLevel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"_top3Stars_Level%ld",(long)_tempLevel];  // Returns _top3Stars_Level1
   // Create the star image based on the stars
   NSString *top3StarsImage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld-stars.png",(long)_tempStar];  // Returns 2-stars.png

   // Doesn't work
   top3StarsLevel.image = [UIImage imageNamed:top3StarsImage];

   // Doesn't work
   top3StarsLevel = [NSString stringWithFormat:top3StarsImage];
```

I feel I'm close, but been working on this for a while now.

Comment: Is there a question here?

Comment: Yes, instead of hard coding all the images, I'm trying to set up everything in a For loop.  The last two lines of code are not working when using the variable names.  May be a syntax problem, but I'm not sure how else to write it.

Comment: What do you do later in the for-loop, after you set the top3StarsLevel image/string? Also, I'm finding it difficult to follow what exactly you're doing. Levels, points, stars... More explanation about what the end result should be would help.

Comment: I'm recalling data from NSUserDefault (level = 1, stars = 2), then creating two strings from the data.  The first string is the name of my image on my storyboard (_top3Stars_Level1).  The next string is what I want that image to be (2-stars.png).  If i hard code "_top3Stars_Level1.image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"2-stars.png"];" this works.  But I'm looping through multiple levels, so for each level, I want to assign the image on my storyboard the corrent .png file.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes that makes more sense. what does the allLevelStatsArray contain? It appears to be an array of arrays? I'm working on a solution but would need some more specifics to get it close to what I think you need.

Comment: The array is created by:  "NSArray *finalLevelStatsArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithLong:keyLevel], [NSNumber numberWithLong:keyScore], [NSNumber numberWithLong:keyStar], nil];"  I then recall it and assign _tempLevel and _tempStars the values (1 and 2 in this example).  I'm using those to create my strings.

Comment: I'm trying to understand this process but it's really not making a whole lot of sense so far... Why are you looping 10 times?

Comment: I have 10 levels.  On the final screen I want to show each level and how many stars they got.  I have 10 level images (each with the name 1-10) and 4 star levels.  So lets say for Level 5, I got 3 stars.  I want image named "_top3Stars_Level5" to show image "3-stars.png"  I loop through all the levels so it's updated at the end no matter what level was played.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there are a few things I would likely change about the way you've structured your data (i.e. I would probably use a dictionary for each "level" to identify the level, score, stars, etc) here is something that I think may get you on the right track:

```
// I'm assuming you have properties/instance variables to reference these image views... Either way, you're going
// to want to reference them in order when you iterate through the levels, so I would recommend putting them in
// an array like this:
NSArray *levelImageViewArray = @[_top3Stars_Level1, _top3Stars_Level2, _top3Stars_Level3, _top3Stars_Level4, _top3Stars_Level5, _top3Stars_Level6, _top3Stars_Level7, _top3Stars_Level8, _top3Stars_Level9, _top3Stars_Level10];

// using your current model, there's an array for each level, and each array holds the level, the score (we're ignoring
// the score for now) and the number of stars
NSArray *levelStatsArray = @[@[@1, @11, @1], @[@2, @22, @2], @[@3, @33, @3], @[@4, @1, @3], @[@5, @22, @2], @[@6, @33, @3], @[@7, @1, @1], @[@8, @22, @2], @[@9, @33, @2], @[@10, @33, @3]];

// loop through the level stats array, starting at 0
for (NSInteger index = 0; index < levelStatsArray.count; index++) {
    // get the stats sub-array for the current level
    NSArray *arrayForLevel = levelStatsArray[index];

    // get the current level and star value, which are the first and third values respectively 
    // in the sub array, and convert the NSNumbers to their NSString values
    NSString *currentLevel = [arrayForLevel[0] stringValue];
    NSString *starsForThisLevel = [arrayForLevel[2] stringValue];

    // generate the stars filename from the 3rd value in the array for this level
    NSString *starsFilename = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-stars.png", starsForThisLevel]];

    // log the info
    NSLog(@"level: %@, starsFilename: %@", currentLevel, starsFilename);

    // create the level and star image from the level/star strings
    UIImage *starsImage = [UIImage imageNamed:starsFilename];

    // get a reference to the specific image view you have for this level
    UIImageView *imageViewForThisLevel = levelImageViewArray[index];
    [imageViewForThisLevel setImage:starsImage];
}
```

That produced the following output:

```
level: 1, starsFilename: 1-stars.png
level: 2, starsFilename: 2-stars.png
level: 3, starsFilename: 3-stars.png
level: 4, starsFilename: 3-stars.png
level: 5, starsFilename: 2-stars.png
level: 6, starsFilename: 3-stars.png
level: 7, starsFilename: 1-stars.png
level: 8, starsFilename: 2-stars.png
level: 9, starsFilename: 2-stars.png
level: 10, starsFilename: 3-stars.png
```

Comment: This looks promising.  I'll try this when I get home.  I can't log in remotely anymore for some reason.  Will definitely vote the answer if works.  This is much cleaner than mine.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: This worked!  Thanks for the help.  How did I get a "-1" with multiple lines showing my technique didn't work?  O well, you fixed my problem